# Original kapt is deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I have changed Kotlin version to 1.2.30. After the update I unable to run the project. I got the below error message.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> app: Original kapt is deprecated. Please add "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'" to your build.gradle.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> **Source**: Annotation Processing with Kotlin
>
> Source Link 1: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html
>
> Source Link 2:https://github.com/uber/NullAway/issues/75

Kotlin plugin doesn't pick up `annotationProcessor` dependencies, So we have to use kapt dependencies with `kotlin-kapt`.

Use the latest version of Kotlin annotation processor put this line at top of your module's level `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Like

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'  // add this line

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
      ........
    }
}
```

Don't forget to update the version when you use different build plugin version.

Comment: I discovered this after installing Realm. Although the addition of 'apply plugin' fixed the warning, Gradle would improperly detect Butterknife's annotation processor.

Answer (score 15):

Add kotlin-kapt plugin in your app-level build.gradle file.

Update your gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'  // add this line

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
      ........
    }
}
```

Comment: `kapt` plugin should be added at the last. It matters.

Answer (score 8):

open your app level gradle file and add this line like this shown in the image and sync you are good to go..

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error after adding `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` so the problem was the order of statements. This order worked for me

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

// add these line in the bulid.gradle(app) module in the top
```

Answer (score 1):

Added in app level gradel file like this.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add the following code snipet in your Gradle module file:**
I had the same problem and it worked for me after syncing the project.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// add following line in build.gradle(Module:app) file at the end of plugin section

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def room_version = "2.5.0"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
```

you must use this in dependencies

```
    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    
    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")
```

and befeore that add this into

```
plugins {
    
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on the latest version.

Add the below code in the app-level build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Actually the real problem is in the order of lines i was also wasted time in it finally i figure out this try like this you will get rid from this

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"
```

Comment: `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"` needs to be embedded in `dependencies {  ... } `