# Unable to use Kotlin-kapt with kotlin/native

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt, kotlin-native

Compiler fails to recognise any kapt dependencies when used in common kotlin/native module

```
apply plugin: 'konan'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-common'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
//kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
}

konan.targets = ['iphone', 'iphone_sim']
def frameworkName = 'XplatformAnalytics'
konanArtifacts {
framework(frameworkName)
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49293777/5167909

Comment: This does not work when used with 'kotlin-platform-android'

Comment: Are you add this line on gradle file: *apply plugin: 'com.android.application'*

Comment: That doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin/Native currently does not support kapt or any other kotlinx libraries. We can use kapt, in android platform of the app, but not in the main common module itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```