# Hilt - cannot be initialized ViewModelFactory in fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

i'am using retrofit library to get info from internet api , then i put the data in the repository then get it in viewmodel which it will be instatiate by viewmodelfactory ;

so i'am trying to inject HitViewModelFactory by using Dagger-Hilt in Fragment but it show me an error when to inject it in the fragment

> lateinit property hitViewModelFactory has not been initialized

i make an application class and anotate it with **@HiltAndroidApp** and give the name of application in manifest. and make anotate to activity that host this fragment but the problem not solved

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

 .......
}
}
```

i provide all dependencies that i need in the module class :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideHitPhotoApi() = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create(HitApi::class.java)

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideHitRepository(hitApi: HitApi) = HitRepository(hitApi)

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideHitViewModelFactory(hitRepository: HitRepository) : HitViewModelFactory = HitViewModelFactory(hitRepository)

 }
```

and try to inject ViewModelFactory in this fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TripsFragment : Fragment() {

@Inject
lateinit var hitViewModelFactory: HitViewModelFactory

lateinit var hitViewModel: HitViewModel


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    hitViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),hitViewModelFactory)[HitViewModel::class.java ]

}
```

dependency for hilt :

```
    Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0- 
    alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem solved when i change the dependency of Hilt to :

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
```

and for these dependencies it should replace the InstallIn anotation for module class to SingletonComponent::class like

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue earlier. Not sure why this fails but it seems code is correct.
So I have done with different approach.
I created view model like this below. And I inject HitApi directly in viewmodel constructor. Then just initialize like below. It takes care of creating viewmodel instance and hilt takes care of injection.No need of creating factory.

**ViewModel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class HitViewModel @Inject constructor(
    var api: HitApi) : ViewModel() {
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
class TripsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<HitViewModel>() //No need of inject annotation.

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
}
```

Make sure you have these dependancies.

```
//For activity
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1'
//For fragment
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.1'
```

Comment: You need module object class. But you dont need that factory injection function there. Without having viewmodel factory you can use viewmodel like this. It will create viewmodel with lazy initialization.

Comment: accourding to your code i don't need to ViewModelFactory class and only should put HitApi as a dependency in module class?

Comment: Yes. As you mentioned.

Comment: the code throw an error "Cause: com.example.Hilt_Application" although the i name the application in manifest

Comment: Full error message?

Comment: this is: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidEntryPointTransformForDebug' ;;  is there any problem with application class for hilt

Comment: I think you are missing kapt plugin. Here is a reference question if you have not applied.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134860/original-kapt-is-deprecated